# Create an array from a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON in the below format

```
waypoints = [
{
lat: 22,
lng: 44
},

{
lat: 55,
lng: 77
}

]
```

I need to convert it into the following format using JS

```
[[22, 44], [55, 77]]
```

Please can some one help me with a solution

Comment: Have you even tried searching for a similar question?

Comment: There is no JSON in your question. That's an array initializer containing object initializers. If you're in JavaScript source code, you're not dealing with JSON (unless it's inside a string).

Answer (score 4):

Just use `map`.

```
var foo = waypoints.map(function(waypoint){
  return [waypoint.lat, waypoint.lng];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new array with use of `.map` method which in execution creates a new array without modifying the original array:

```js
var waypoints = [{
  lat: 22,
  lng: 44
}, {
  lat: 55,
  lng: 77
}];

var newArr = waypoints.map(function(obj) {
  return [obj.lat, obj.lng];
});

document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(newArr);
```

Comment: I recommend to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to understand how `.map()` works and what it is meant for

Comment: @Andreas true! i always miss about `.map()` method.

Comment: @RGraham I will take care of that now on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for...in loop and get the array

```
var array=[];

for(var i =0;i< waypoints.length;i++){
var nestedArray=[];
  for(var key in waypoints[i]){
      nestedArray.push(waypoints[i][key])
    }
   array.push(nestedArray)
 }
```

---

Found other answers using `map` functionality of JavaScript. Thats good!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
var waypoints = [
    {
        lat: 22,
        lng: 44
    },
    {
        lat: 55,
        lng: 77
    }
];
var array = [];
for (i in waypoints) {
    array.push([]);
    for (j in waypoints[i]) {
        array[i].push(waypoints[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use:
    waypoints = [{lat: 22, lng: 44   }, { lat: 55, lng: 77   } ];
     var innerArr = [];
     var requiredArray = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < waypoints.length; i++) {
         innerArr = [];
         innerArr.push(waypoints[i].lat);
         innerArr.push(waypoints[i].lng);
         requiredArray.push(innerArr);
     }
```